# What are the possible reasons visual studio 2008 team system would not connect to a TFS2008 server

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I have Visual Studio 2008 Team System installed on my work machine. I use it to work for an offisite clients Team Foundation Server 2008.

Yesterday it stopped working. E.G. I couldn't connect to TFS.

On my machine I have updates disabled, I have the firewall disabled and have a proper working connection to my clients server.

The client didn't change anything on its machine.

What are the possible reasons the visual studio couldn't find the TFS server.

Note: Other members of my team can connect without problems, and I've checked we have the same configurations).

Answer (score 0):

I have had som similar problems in our project.

We have a team foundation server 2008 and the clients use visual studio 2008 with team explorer and service pack 1. Some of the team members can't connect via team explorer but others can connect without problem.

We solved the problem when we did test/find out that all necessary user had to belong to licensed team foundation server group. You manually have to add all users to this tfs group inside from team explorer menu.